# Can't compile R package

Tags: c++, r, compiler-errors, package

I am the author of https://github.com/akoyabio/rtree. Until recently, I was able to develop the package in RStudio on Windows with no problems. I was able to check and install the package without any error.

Something has changed and I can no longer build the package. In RStudio, "Install and restart" (with `--debug`) gives the output

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source --debug rtree

Loading C:\Users\kjohnson\Documents\Rprofile.site 
processing 'rtree'
a directory
* installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/Library'
* build_help_types=html
* DBG: 'R CMD INSTALL' now doing do_install()
* created lock directory 'C:/Program Files/R/Library/00LOCK-rtree'
* installing *source* package 'rtree' ...
** backing up earlier installation
** libs
about to run R CMD SHLIB -o rtree.dll RcppExports.cpp rtree.cpp --debug
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rtree'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/Library/rtree'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/Library/rtree'
In R CMD INSTALL

Exited with status 1.
```

I'm looking for help troubleshooting this error. How can I get more details about the failure?

I *do* have RTools installed, at `C:\RTools`, and my `PATH` includes both
`C:\Rtools\bin` and `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin`.

Note: I see the same error if I create a new Rcpp project in RStudio and try to build it. Thank you for any suggestions...

Comment: Builds and checks for me (on Linux). Minor nags are i) you should not commit the object file and shared library in `src/` and ii) `BH` does not belong in `Imports:`.  Otherwise passes `R CMD build ...` and `R CMD check ...` fine for me.

Comment: Which is to say ... the error is likely with your local setup, and for that we may well be unable to help from here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I agree, there is some problem with my local machine. I'm looking for help with diagnosing the failure. How can I get more information about what specifically is failing? I don't know any details about how the code is actually built.

Comment: You are the only one with access to your machine so I suggest you double check installation FAQs, and/or check your on the available free service:  https://builder.r-hub.io/ is good for this.

Answer (score 1):

I never really found out how to get more visibility into the failure. I did find the cause - it was an anti-virus program called Minerva's Shield. Turning it off allowed me to build again.